# How to use method-based and class-based authorization for a controller class at the same time?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to include Spring Security Basic Authentication in my project. I want to do both method-based and class-based authorization for a controller class. So the teacher will be able to access all end points in my controller class. But only some of them will be accessible to students. How do I provide this?

I added `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('TEACHER')")` above my class and added `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('STUDENT')")` above some of the methods. But I couldn't do what I wanted. What do you think I should do?

Comment: You have to annotate your methods with both roles. Method annotation overrides class annotation.

Answer (score 0):

As @dur has suggested, there isn't a way to 'extend' the authorized roles for methods of a Controller (not any that I know of, at least). That being said, there is a nice way to implement the functionality you want. Let's say you have a controller named `StudiesController`:

```java
@RestController
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('TEACHER')") //annotating the controller class with PreAuthorize will provide "default" required acccess for all of the controller's methods
public class StudiesController {

    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('STUDENT', 'TEACHER')")  //both students AND teachers have to to be able to access the study schedule. hence, we override the "default" required access to also allow students to access this method
    @GetMapping("/schedule")
    public Map<String, String> getSchedule() {
        //some code
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/grades/{studentId}")
    public Map<String, Integer> getGradesOfStudent(@PathVariable Integer studentId) {   //only teachers have to be able to access a student's grades, so we do not override the "default" access level
       //some code
    }

}
```

Basically, every method will only be accessible by Teachers by default. Any method you wish to make accessible to some other role, you annotate with `@PreAuthorize` and use the `hasAnyRole` method to list the allowed roles. This does lead to you having to write `'TEACHER'` for such methods, though.

Also, do not forget to add `@EnableMethodSecurity` to your `SecurityConfig` class to enable the `@PreAuthorize` annotations